# Extract text regardless of the order

Tags: excel, extract

I have a problem with Excel
I  have one column with text and I want to extract string according these conditions: for string that contain 'SAC' or 'REC' show 'n' and for string that contain 'ABC' show 'y'

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnO6T.jpg)

I tried use these functions
IF.ERROR(find("ABC",S41), "y")
but for those who do not meet the condition does not show me the required value

Comment: And what, exactly, is your problem with Excel?  What have you tried, and what isn't working?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
=if(or(isnumber(find("REC", c4)), isnumber(find("SAC", c4))), "n", "")&if(isnumber(find("ABC", c4)), "y", "")
```